# Is it possible to own an unlimited number of companies?

Tags: limits

Is there a limit to how many companies you can create or own? Such as Google owns <strike>Facebook</strike>, YouTube, <strike>Twitter</strike>, Google Play Store, Google Games, etc. But those are all branches of Google and not actual companies. What I want to know is can I buy an unlimited amount of companies, or will someone stop me from doing it?

Comment: To buy and own an unlimited number of companies you would theoretically need an unlimited amount of money as well...

Comment: Google doesn't own Facebook, btw.

Comment: As Aganju noted, Google doesn't own FB or Twitter. Also, some of those ARE actual companies.  They have their own corporate structures (i.e. YouTube is a subsidiary of Google).  Google itself has a parent company - Alphabet.

Comment: And Alphabet owns Google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can own unlimited companies, with the caveat that once you gain market power in a market 'niche' or 'vertical', further merger announcements will bring you serious resistance from the FTC and DOJ during the review period of the [Hart–Scott–Rodino Antitrust Improvements Act of 1976](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hart%E2%80%93Scott%E2%80%93Rodino_Antitrust_Improvements_Act).